# Merge Replication - Invalid Column Name

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, merge-replication

Good Day everyone,

I am battling with a merge replication. I added a new column to an existing Merge Replication and Rerun the snapshot.

This replicates to 3 different servers in different locations. 1 Replication works perfectly, but 2 of the replication fails with the following error:

> The schema script 'ProductionCategories_8.prc' could not be propagated
>   to the subscriber. (Source: MSSQL_REPL, Error number:
>   MSSQL_REPL-2147201001) Get help: http://help/MSSQL_REPL-2147201001
>   Invalid column name 'SortOrder'. (Source: MSSQLServer, Error number:
>   207) Get help: http://help/207

When viewing the table where the referenced column is located the Column is in both the publisher and relevant subscribers.

I also checked spelling and case to ensure there are no Case Sensitivity or silly spelling mistakes, but all is fine.

I really need to get this sorted as group reporting is being hampered by this.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like possibly a permission issue. Have you seen this article? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/mssql-repl-2147201001

Comment: This error is common when SQL attempts to parse a stored procedure prior to applying it at the subscriber. Schema is validated at this point and the article will not be applied if not valid. Is there anything that would cause the schema validation to fail? I would do a triple check just to be sure.

Comment: I had the same issue. Were you able to get the `Invalid column name` error fixed?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I eventually reinitialized the replication

Comment: @MardusDavel Do you use User Defined Types?

Answer (score 0):

I eventually Reinitialized the replication and this resolved the issue